# PS4 – DLC installed on wrong version of game

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, psn, dark-souls-3

There are two versions of Dark Souls 3 on my PS4. The first disc version from when I borrowed it from my friend, and the second disc version that I bought for myself afterwards. I use the second version obviously since I still have the disc.

Recently however I purchased the DLC, and it downloaded fine and installed.

However I cannot access the DLC. I have searched online and none of the solutions help. So I searched in the Storage to see what was up. What I found was that the version of Dark Souls I never use had both DLCs installed (fig. 1 & 2) and the other (the one I use) had none (fig. 3).

How do I switch the DLC to the version that I have the actual disc for?

Do I have to contact Sony or something? Is there a way to merge the two versions of the game?

––**Fig. 1 The version I don't have**––
[image]

––**Fig. 2 The Installed Add-Ons for the version I don't have**––
[image]

––**Fig. 3 The Version I have**––
[image]

––**Fig. 4 Side by side (One I have is on right)**––
[image]

Comment: Why would you not just uninstall the other version? Or why not start to use the version with the DLCs? You can easily transfer your savegames

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Would that work? Wouldn't deleting the other version still mean my one doesn't work? I can't start using the old one btw because I no longer have the disc for that version.

Comment: It seems you somehow managed to buy a disk from a different region as your friend's. Notice how "Parental Control" isn't the same for both versions. I'm honestly not sure how you could fix this without re-purchasing either the game or DLCs. Maybe ask Sony Support for advice? They could at least try to exchange your DLC for the correct ones (maybe).